# How to save bookmarks with names in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

When I create a bookmark the name and project that I enter are not saved when I click Close.

The manual says there should be an OK button but there isn't. Using QGIS 1.8

Comment: It might help to include a screenshot of what you are entering, and then what is in the window when you reopen it.  When you are creating a new bookmark, are you using the `New Bookmark` option under the **View** menu, or are you using the `Show Bookmarks` option and then using the `Add` button in the **Geospatial Bookmarks** window?  A little more detail on the process may help narrow down where the error is occurring.

Comment: I tried both methods, and it works as expected with Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

After entering text in a field in the bookmarks menu you just need to 'click off it' by clicking once in some other row for the changes to be saved.

I prefer to avoid using the close button on the bookmarks menu. :)